# Best way to use streaming withWindows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, streaming

With Android/BlackBerry I can use RTSP:

```
<a href="rtsp://my.rtsp.service/(...).stream">link</a>
```

With iOS I can use:

```
<audio src="http://my.service.url/(...)playlist.m3u">/<audio>
```

With desktop computers, I can use Flash to play RTMP.

I have a link like this to run with with Windows Phone, but I don't know how to use it:

```
http://mediadl.microsoft.com/mediadl/iisnet/smoothmedia/Experience/BigBuckBunny_720p.ism/Manifest
```

I'm not using Visual Studio here. I just want to put this streaming to work with Windows Phone devices. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can follow this tutorial [from MSDN](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/risman/archive/2012/02/04/windows-phone-7-video-smooth-streaming-client.aspx), but mediaelement doesn't support smooth streaming videos, so in order to play smooth streaming videos you will have to download [Microsoft Media Platform: Player Framework](http://smf.codeplex.com/) (there is simple project, so try it before implement)

When i had to deal with smooth streaming videos, it turns out that some windows phone 7 phones support different maximal resolution, also The WP7 platform does not currently support multiple resolution video tracks. (reference [here](http://blog.supaywasi.com/2013/01/smooth-streaming-multi-resolution-support-for-windows-phone/) and [here](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Video_playback_guidance_for_Nokia_Lumia_610))

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'm seeing I need to develop an application first before to use the streaming, correct? How could I call the application from my website (running on IE)?

Comment: sorry, i don't think i can help you there mate, maybe you can use  Player Framework, it is for browser-based video playback http://playerframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Player%20Framework%20for%20HTML5&referringTitle=Home